# Retrofit and Realm access from another thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit, realm

I am using Realm for database service and Retrofit for server service. 
I want to get data from Realm and pass it as object to Retrofit, but I get following error :

```
     retrofit.RetrofitError: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created.
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-25 12:58:36.418   W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created.
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at io.realm.Realm.checkIfValid(Realm.java:192)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at io.realm.DisabilitiesRealmProxy.isWheelchair(DisabilitiesRealmProxy.java:47)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at io.realm.DisabilitiesRealmProxy.toString(DisabilitiesRealmProxy.java:238)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RequestBuilder.setArguments(RequestBuilder.java:312)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:298)
05-25 12:58:36.423   W/System.err﹕ ... 7 more
```

It all starts here :

```
if (ConnectionUtils.isConnectionToInternetEnabled(this)) {
        PlaceServerService.getPlaces("London", DatabaseAdapter.getDisabilities(this));
    }
```

Which calls this method :

```
public static void getPlaces(String city, Disabilities disabilities) {
    PlaceClient client = createService(PlaceClient.class);
    client.getPlaces(city, disabilities, new Callback<PlaceResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void success(PlaceResponse placeResponse, Response response) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(placeResponse.getPlaces());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

And interface to this :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/places/city")
void getPlaces(@Field("city") String city,
               @Field("disabilities") Disabilities disabilities,
               Callback<PlaceResponse> callback);
```

I don't see, where it has this thread issue here? I am just passing object to the Retrofit method. Maybe the problem is that `Disabilities` object extends `RealmObject`?

EDIT :

However, this solution works, why?

```
if (ConnectionUtils.isConnectionToInternetEnabled(this)) {
        Disabilities disabilities = DatabaseAdapter.getDisabilities(this);
        Disabilities disability = new Disabilities(
                disabilities.isWheelchair(),
                disabilities.isBlind(),
                disabilities.isDeaf(),
                disabilities.isOtherMovement());
        PlaceServerService.getPlaces("London", disability);
    }
```

Comment: To break that realm limitation, you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602258/how-to-achieve-the-following-in-realm-for-android/32607241#32607241 . it shows wrapper kind of implementation to free your application from Realm access from incorrect thread exception

Comment: i have same issue. thanks for asking.

Comment: @savepopulation no problem mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah `Disabilities` extends `RealmObject` and is part of the `Realm`. What you could do is create a new object:

```
Disabilities disabilities = new Disabilities();
```

And then put the content that's inside the `Disabilities` in your new object. This works because this object is not in `Realm` yet.

Comment: I did so and it works (see edit), however it is a bit workaround, I am curious if there is better solution. If not this is a correct answer.

Comment: @kodw I haven't found another solution. [Here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/931) is the feature request to have a copy method out of `Realm`. When that feature request gets implemented you can handle this in an easier way. Also I don't really know how Retrofit works, I'm assuming it converts the object to `JSON`. Maybe you can ask for a `String` instead of `Disabilities` and use `GSON` to convert the `Disabilities` to a `String`?